# How .NET Dictionary implementation works with mutable objects

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, hashtable

I understand that it is not advisable to use "mutable" objects (objects whose GetHashCode() method can return different results while they being used as keys in a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)).

Below is my understanding of how a dictionary, which is implemented as a hash table, works:

When I am adding new key, for example `dict.Add(m1, "initially here was m1 object");`, `dict` calculates the hashcode of `m1` using the `GetHashCode()` method. Then it does some internal calculations and finally puts this object into some position of its internal array.

When I am using the key index to get the value, for example `dict[m1]`, `dict` calculates the hashcode again. Then it does some internal calculations, and it gives me an object which is located at the calculated position inside of its internal array.

But I think there is an error which I can't find.

So lets assume that I have this code:

```
    class MutableObject
    {
         Int32 m_value;

         public MutableObject(Int32 value)
         {
             m_value = value;
         }

         public void Mutate(Int32 value)
         {
             m_value = value;
         }

         public override int GetHashCode()
         {
             return m_value;
         }
   }

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
         MutableObject m1 = new MutableObject(1);
         MutableObject m2 = new MutableObject(2);

         var dict = new Dictionary<MutableObject, String>();
         dict.Add(m1, "initially here was m1 object");
         dict.Add(m2, "initially here was m2 object");

         Console.WriteLine("Before mutation:");
         Console.WriteLine("dict[m1] = " + dict[m1]);
         Console.WriteLine("dict[m2] = " + dict[m2]);

         m1.Mutate(2);
         m2.Mutate(1);

         Console.WriteLine("After mutation:");
         Console.WriteLine("dict[m1] = " + dict[m1]);
         Console.WriteLine("dict[m2] = " + dict[m2]);

         Console.ReadKey(true);
   }
```

When I call `Mutate` methods, keys are swapped. So I thought it will give swapped results. But actually this line: `Console.WriteLine("dict[m1] = " + dict[m1]);` throws KeyNotFoundException, and I can't understand why. Obviously I am missing something here...

Comment: There are only four billion possible hash codes. Suppose just by bad luck you have two unequal objects in the same hash table with the same hash code. *How does the dictionary tell them apart*?  When you answer that question, you will understand why your program is giving you the results that you're seeing.

Comment: I know that hasttable can implement chaining, or open addressing alghoritms, for example, to fight with collisions. So when I call for `dict[m1]` he get hash code, equals 2 after swapping, then... what he does? He trying to figure out, which object with this hashcode is right, which of them he should return...

Comment: You buy a house at 1 Elm Street, then buy the house at 2 Elm Street and move there.  You change the address sign on the second house to 1 Elm Street.  Where does the mail to 1 Elm Street get delivered?

Comment: Good analogue, thank you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How .NET Dictionary implementation works with mutable objects

It doesn't.  The [documentation for Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) states:

> As long as an object is used as a key in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, it must not change in any way that affects its hash value.

Since you're changing the object while it's in the `Dictionary` it will not work.

As for why, it's not too hard to see.  We put in an object.  Let's assume that the hash code is `1`.  We put the object in the `1` bucket of our hash table.  Now the object is mutated from outside the Dictionary so that it's value (and hash code) is `2`.  Now when someone gives that object to the dictionary's indexer it gets the hash code, see's that it's `2`, and looks in the `2` bucket.  That bucket is empty, so it says, "sorry, no element".

Now let's assume that a new object is created with a value and hash of `1`.  It's passed to the Dictionary, who sees that the hash is `1`.  It looks in the `1` bucket and finds that there is indeed an item at that index.  It now uses `Equals` to determine if the objects are in fact equal (or if this is just a hash collision).

Now, in your case, it will fail here because you don't override `Equals`, you're using the default implementation which compares references, and since this is a different object it won't have the same reference.  However, even if you changed it to compare the values, *the first object was mutated to have a value of `2`, not `1`, so it won't match anyway.  Others have suggested fixing this `Equals` method, and you really should do that, *but it still won't fix your problem*.

Once the object is mutated the only way of finding it is if it just so happens that the mutated value is a hash collision (which is possible, but unlikely).  If it's not, then anything that is equal according to `Equals` will never know to check the right bucket, and anything that checks the right bucket won't be equal according to `Equals`.

The quote I mentioned at the start isn't just a best practice.  It's not just unexpected or weird or unperformant to mutate items in a dictionary.  *It just doesn't work*.

Now, if the object is mutable *but isn't mutated while it's in the dictionary* then that's fine.  It may be a bit odd, and *that's* a case people may say is bad practice, even if it works.

Comment: Interesting note: the “hash collision” you mentioned happens only when the mutated value has the same hash code as the original value, it's not enough if both fall into the same bucket (because `Dictionary` compares the full hash codes before comparing equality).

Comment: @svick That's what I was referring to, but I didn't explore the example in depth as it doesn't seem worth explaining.

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to do a dictionary lookup to have the same hash code.  Since hash collisions are possible, the key must also be equal the index being looked up.

Comment: Even with that change, it won't work.  `Dictionary` assumes that items added to it won't have their hash code's changed while they are n the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Your `MutableObject` class doesn't override `Equals(object)`. Hence reference equality is used (inherited from base class `System.Object`).

The `Dictionary<,>` first (quickly) finds any keys with the correct hash code. It then examines each of those candidate keys to check if one of them `Equals` the key it is searching for.

Therefore `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()` should be overridden together. You would get a *warning* from the compiler if you overrode only one of them.

As soon as the hash code of a key mutates while the key is in the `Dictionary<,>`, that key will (probably) be misplaced inside the `Dictionary<,>`, be in the wrong "bucket", and hence be lost. It will not be found, because search for it will always take place in a bucket where it isn't located.

In this example, the key gets lost, and therefore can be added again:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<MutableObject, string>();

var m = new MutableObject(1);

dict.Add(m, "Hello");

m.Mutate(2);

dict.Add(m, "world");

foreach (var p in dict)
    Console.WriteLine(p);

var otherDict = new Dictionary<MutableObject, string>(dict); // throws
```

I have actually seen an exception like that, during initializing of one `Dictionary<,>` with the items from an existing `Dictionary<,>` (both using the default `EqualityComparer<>` for the key type).