# Same dictionary key for a class instances with identical fields' values

Tags: c#, dictionary

1. I have this class

   ```
   class Border
   {
      int top;
      int bottom;
      int left;
      int right;
   }
   ```
2. And I have a `Dictionary` with `Border` as a key.

I want to have the same key for this class, if these two values are equal. How can I do it?

Comment: I cannot understand your question

Comment: rephrase "**I want to have the same key for this class if this values equals.**"

Comment: If you mean duplicate keys, that is not allowed.  If that is what you need, then you don't need a Dictionary.

Comment: Are you just asking how to override `.Equals()`?

Comment: You want your Dictionary to hold duplicate keys?

Comment: Do you want to check if there is another 'KeyValuePair' that has the same value and when this is true, then don't add the new value to your dictionary?

Comment: @DonBoitnott sure it is, you just redefine what "duplicate" means in the given context. I'm not sure if that's what they are asking about, or indeed the exact opposite.

Comment: @JonHanna `Dictionary` enforces unique keys.  It's not up to anyone but the framework to define duplicate.  Unless you are suggesting that OP roll their own `Dictionary` class?

Comment: @DonBoitnott Dictionary enforces unique keys by the definition of uniqueness it is created to use. This is why its constructor takes an argument of type `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` (though defaulting to `EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default`). Dictionaries would be very limited otherwise (e.g. imagine if we couldn't have case-insensitive string keys).

Comment: Some good French documentation to understand Equals and GetHashCode :
http://www.olivettom.com/?p=541

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, if these need to go as keys in a dictionary, then [your class needs to be immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439134/why-should-dictionary-keys-be-immutable). Then it's a case of adding equality and a hashcode implementation (thankyou resharper).

```
public class Border
{
    private readonly int bottom;
    private readonly int left;
    private readonly int right;
    private readonly int top;

    public Border(int top, int left, int bottom, int right)
    {
        this.top = top;
        this.left = left;
        this.bottom = bottom;
        this.right = right;
    }

    protected bool Equals(Border other)
    {
        return bottom == other.bottom && left == other.left && right == other.right && top == other.top;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Border) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = bottom;
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ left;
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ right;
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ top;
            return hashCode;
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Border left, Border right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Border left, Border right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }

    public int Top
    {
        get { return top; }
    }

    public int Bottom
    {
        get { return bottom; }
    }

    public int Left
    {
        get { return left; }
    }

    public int Right
    {
        get { return right; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Equals` override tests type, non-nullity and border-specific equality in three separate steps; `return Equals(obj as Border)` would do all three.

Comment: Resharper's override... Suggest you address your concerns to JetBrainz ;)

Comment: Why you did not implement IComparable?

Comment: For brevity? Is it necessary?

Comment: It will throw a nullRef exception because `Equals(Border b)` does not check for nullity.

Comment: @Thomas: Go for it... http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Issue+Tracker

Comment: I was just interested I thought it is a good practice...

Comment: @spender, I was answering to Jon Hanna ;-)

Comment: I don't use Resharper, so if it's producing lousy code that's not my problem (though if it's just intended as a starting point fair enough). The weird thing is that the only reason I can think of for using `obj.GetType() != this.GetType()` rather than `obj is Border` is to avoid CA1800 warnings from tools like FxCop.

Comment: I'd say that "lousy" is a bit strong...

Comment: If it's in three lines and from a tool that is meant to help one improve quality, I'd have a much tougher line for "lousy" than otherwise. It's fine but improvable as hand-written. It's better than the auto-gen SharpDevelop would give, but I thought ReSharper was supposed to remove code smells and aid refactoring. By that standard, it's lousy.

Comment: @JonHanna http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx See the first large code sample and commentary under it. `GetType() == other.GetType()` is often preferable in `Equals()` implementations because it checks that the two objects have the same runtime type. Objects should generally not be considered equal if they have the same effective values but different types.

Comment: @jlrishe, then that should be considered in the other equals overload. Indeed, you've pointed out a bug; either the normal case you describe holds, in which case the other equals overload is buggy for not catching it, or there is a reason for allowing an exception to that guideline, so the second overload is buggy for the opposite reason, or else the class should be sealed to make that case impossible. Whichever of the three is the correct case, Equals(other as Border) would be the correct overload, bar the case where some instances should be equal to null (very rarely correct).

Comment: @Dannydust Implementing `IComparable` would not make much sense here, but implementing `IEquatable<Border>` would be worthwhile and only require another 18 characters. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734914/whats-the-difference-between-iequatable-and-just-overriding-object-equals

Comment: @JonHanna It's probably worth noting that R# gives you three different options concerning comparisons with subclasses (comparand type check: "exactly the same type as this" OR "exactly of type Border" OR "Equal or subtype of Border") and will trot out different implementations dependent on what you choose. FWIW, I chose "exactly the same type as this".

Comment: @JLRishe: Uh, mixed it up. In fact I was meaning IEquatable. Thx for pointing it out.

Comment: I like that choice in a tool, though the overload accepting border arguments is buggy by that requirement. Resharper does seem less crazy with that pointed out though. Would it produce the same code if the class was sealed?

Comment: @JLRishe, always worth doing; it makes the default comparer that will actually call these methods for the dictionary faster, and can catch some silly typo-level errors.

Comment: @JLRishe actually, thinking about there's three viable configurations, either the equatable class must be sealed (my normal preference) or it must force descendants to be unequal (with GetType() == other.GetType() in the more strongly typed override), or in rare cases it must seal `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to force the descendants to be equal by the same rule. It occurs to me that in a handful of cases where I've had a sensibly inheritable equality, I haven't sealed those methods to prevent bugs, so thanks for pointing me to that insight.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you mean one of two opposite things.

If you mean that you want to make sure two different instances of `border` are counted as being the same key if their values are the same then you need to redefine equality.

Step 1. Implement `IEquatable<Border>`, while you don't need to do so, it makes some things faster to run and other things simpler to code.

Step 2. Add your code to implement the `Equals` method this requires:

```
public bool Equals(Border other)
{
  return other != null
    && other.bottom == bottom
    && other.top == top
    && other.left == left
    && other.right == right;
}
```

Edit: As JLRishe points out in a comment on another answer, if this class isn't sealed then the above method should check `GetType() == other.GetType()` after the null check, unless it has a very good reason not to).

Step 3. Add an override for `object.Equals` and `object.GetHashCode`:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
  return Equals(other as Border);
}
public override int GetHashCode()
{
   //This is a simple method without very good distribution, that will serve for many cases, but can be improved upon.
   return (bottom << 24 | bottom >> 8)
     ^ (top << 16 | top >> 16)
     ^ (left << 8 | left >> 8)
     ^ right;
}
```

Now the default behaviour of your class when used in a dictionary will be to treat those `Border` objects with the same bottom, top, left and right as being the same thing.

Alternatively, maybe you mean you've already got that, and you want to have two equal objects treated as differently for some reason (as if they didn't have a specific sense of equivalence defined for them). You can't do that in pure C# without reflection emit, so I wrote http://www.nuget.org/packages/AisA/ for the few times it's useful.