# Formatting and getting missing data

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, csv

I'm beginner in c#. I have a data structure ResourceID, EditionId, LocationID, ViewCount, and ClickCount. Each entry has a date and its information. As shown in the following image.

In some days I may get different **EditionID, ResourcesID,ViewCount,ClickCount** but for the same **ResourceID**

I have the following      `var enteries = new Dictionary<IgaAdKey, IgaEntry>();`
Where `IgaAdkey` has `ResourceId,LocationID,EditionID`. `IgaEntry` has `ViewCount` and `ClickCount`.

I also have `HashSet<int>` of all resources that will be there. I also have `Dictionary<string, HashSet<int>> resourcesDate` for Day -> which resources IDs available in that day, so that I can put empty places in that row, if there is a resourceID in the current processing date that is not in that date, so that I put in its row, empty places.

using all that information, I would like to format the table, but I still have problems in populating the data correctly. Sometimes I get a row in wrong place,..etc

The code I use to populate the data:

```
 foreach (IgaAdKey adKey in enteries.Keys)
    {
        IgaEntry entry;

        if (enteries.TryGetValue(adKey, out entry))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(adKey.LocationId + ",");
            streamWriter.Write(adKey.EditionId + ",");
            streamWriter.Write(entry.mClickCount + ",");
            streamWriter.Write(entry.mViewCount + ",");
            streamWriter.Write(",");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                streamWriter.Write(",");
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Update:
[image]

Comment: You need to spend some time narrowing down the problem. You're unlikely to find somebody who's willing to wade through 350 lines of code looking for where you made a mistake. You need to add debugging code that shows you where things are being inserted into the dictionary. It's almost certain that the problem isn't in how you're iterating over the dictionary to output the individual items. It's much more likely that you've made a mistake in the way that you populate the dictionary in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as shown will never output an empty line.  That's because you loop though the `Keys` of the `enteries` dictionary, then try to get the value for the key.  But the value will always be found, since you're looping through the keys.  Better just to loop through the dictionary as a [collection of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects.

There was a [very similar question asked earlier](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412077/sorting-data-in-cvs-from-custom-dictionary) where the problem was to group together dictionary entries with the same `ResourceId` but different values for `EditionId` or `LocationId`.  Assuming this is actually the same issue, one way to do this is to make `IgaAdKey` implement `IComparable<IgaAdKey>` like so:

```
public class IgaAdKey : IEquatable<IgaAdKey>, IComparable<IgaAdKey>
{
    public int ResourceId;
    public int EditionId;
    public int LocationId;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        else if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
            return false;
        if (obj.GetType() != GetType())
            return false;
        var other = (IgaAdKey)obj;
        return ResourceId == other.ResourceId && EditionId == other.EditionId && LocationId == other.LocationId;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ResourceId.GetHashCode() ^ EditionId.GetHashCode() ^ LocationId.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("ResourceId={0}, EditionId={1}, LocationId={2}", ResourceId, EditionId, LocationId);
    }

    #region IEquatable<IgaAdKey> Members

    public bool Equals(IgaAdKey other)
    {
        return Equals((object)other);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IComparable<IgaAdKey> Members

    public int CompareTo(IgaAdKey other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return -1; // At end?
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return 0;
        int diff;
        if ((diff = ResourceId.CompareTo(other.ResourceId)) != 0)
            return diff;
        if ((diff = EditionId.CompareTo(other.EditionId)) != 0)
            return diff;
        if ((diff = LocationId.CompareTo(other.LocationId)) != 0)
            return diff;
        return 0;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Having done this, you can either:

1. Store your objects in a [`SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

   ```
   var enteries = new SortedDictionary<IgaAdKey, IgaEntry>()

   // Build the dictionary

   foreach (var pair in enteries)
   {
       // Write to the CSV file
   }
   ```

   In this case all keys with identical `ResourceId` will be adjacent.
2. Store them in a regular dictionary and sort them for writing:

   ```
   var enteries = new Dictionary<IgaAdKey, IgaEntry>()

   // Build the dictionary

   foreach (var pair in enteries.OrderBy(pair => pair.Key))
   {
       // Write to the CSV file
   }
   ```

Incidentally, if you are going to be using `IgaAdKey` as a dictionary key, you should make it be immutable, for reasons discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439134/why-should-dictionary-keys-be-immutable).

**Update**

Although your question isn't very clear, from your code I was able to determine that you are trying to output a table that is essentially a 2d grid of smaller tables.  Along the X axis are all resource ids, with five columns of data for each.  Along the Y axis are all dates, and for each date, as many rows as needed for each location & edition found for each resource + date combination.

In that case, you need to:

1. Collect up all files and index them by date (you are already doing that).
2. Scan through all the files to find all resource ids (you are already doing that).
3. Sort the list of all resources into some consistent order, so that the output of your program is not random in any way:

   ```
               var allResourcesInOrder = allResources.ToList();
               allResourcesInOrder.Sort();
   ```
4. Output the 5 columns for each resource:

   ```
               foreach (int resourceId in allResourcesInOrder)
               {
                   stream.Write(resourceId + ",");
                   stream.Write("Location ID" + ",");
                   stream.Write("Edition ID" + ",");
                   stream.Write("Click Count" + ",");
                   stream.Write("View Count" + ",");
               }
               stream.Write("\n");
   ```
5. For each date, output cells for each resource found for that date in all files found for that date:

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// reads & merges all the files for one specific date and create iga entry, merge their values, write them to the file
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="date"></param>
   /// <param name="files"></param>
   /// <param name="streamWriter"></param>
   private static void ReadMergeAndWriteFilesForDay(
       DateTime date, List<string> files, StreamWriter streamWriter,
       IList<int> allResourcesInOrder  // Specifies the column order.
       )
   {
       var enteries = new Dictionary<IgaAdKey, IgaEntry>();

       foreach (string fileName in files)
           ReadFileForDay(fileName, enteries);

       var dateResources = new Dictionary<int, List<IgaAdKey>>();
       foreach (var key in enteries.Keys)
           dateResources.Add(key.ResourceId, key);

       // Sort the resources to output them in a consistent order.  Not required but good practice.
       dateResources.SortAll();

       for (int iRow = 0, nRows = dateResources.MaxCount(); iRow < nRows; iRow++)
       {
           for (int index = 0; index < allResourcesInOrder.Count; index++)
           {
               if (index == 0)
                   streamWriter.Write(date.ToDateString() + ",");
               else
                   streamWriter.Write(","); // Date goes under the resource ID for the first resource; otherwise leave it empty.
               int resourceId = allResourcesInOrder[index];
               IgaAdKey key;
               IgaEntry value;
               if (dateResources.TryGetValue(resourceId, iRow, out key)
                   && enteries.TryGetValue(key, out value))
               {
                   streamWriter.Write(key.LocationId + ",");
                   streamWriter.Write(key.EditionId + ",");
                   streamWriter.Write(value.mClickCount + ",");
                   streamWriter.Write(value.mViewCount + ",");
               }
               else
               {
                   streamWriter.Write(",");
                   streamWriter.Write(",");
                   streamWriter.Write(",");
                   streamWriter.Write(",");
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Note `ReadFileForDay` was extracted from the first half of your `MergeFilesForDay`, [here](http://pastebin.com/ygKVKBjv).
6. Add a few useful extension methods to make life easier:

   ```
       public static class Returns
       {
           public static bool False<TValue>(out TValue value)
           {
               value = default(TValue);
               return false;
           }
       }

       public static class ListDictionaryExtensions
       {
           public static void Add<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> listDictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
           {
               if (listDictionary == null)
                   throw new ArgumentNullException();
               List<TValue> values;
               if (!listDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out values))
               {
                   listDictionary[key] = (values = new List<TValue>());
               }
               values.Add(value);
           }

           public static bool TryGetValue<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> listDictionary, TKey key, int index, out TValue value)
           {
               List<TValue> list;
               if (!listDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list))
                   return Returns.False(out value);
               if (index < 0 || index >= list.Count)
                   return Returns.False(out value);
               value = list[index];
               return true;
           }

           public static void SortAll<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> listDictionary)
           {
               if (listDictionary == null)
                   return;
               foreach (var list in listDictionary.Values)
                   list.Sort();
           }

           public static int MaxCount<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> listDictionary)
           {
               if (listDictionary == null)
                   return 0;
               int count = 0;
               foreach (var list in listDictionary.Values)
                   count = Math.Max(count, list.Count);
               return count;
           }
       }
   ```

Full code [here](http://pastebin.com/Q7gLWRqU).  Of course I can't test it since I don't have any of your input files.

Comment: I have tried your way, but still I can get entries in the CVS file that are not there in their date, so I need a way to check if current pair is really in that day, otherwise print some empty commas, but the problem is how to know which place to put. here is the full source code of the program its command line.
http://pastebin.com/ygKVKBjv

Comment: can you see the updated image? I have for example entries like that per day

Answer (score 2):

First, you can simplify your loop like this:

```
foreach (var kvp in enteries)
{
    IgaAdKey = kvp.Key;
    IgaEntry entry = kvp.Value;

    streamWriter.Write(adKey.LocationId + ",");
    streamWriter.Write(adKey.EditionId + ",");
    streamWriter.Write(entry.mClickCount + ",");
    streamWriter.Write(entry.mViewCount + ",");
    streamWriter.Write(",");
}
```

This is the normal way you'd iterate over the keys in a dictionary.

It's hard to say why you are getting "a row in the wrong place." If you want these things in some particular order, then you'll have to sort them. `Dictionary` doesn't guarantee the order of items. You can't expect to get things out of the dictionary in the same order you inserted them.

I suspect that the trouble you're having has more to do with the items you're adding to the dictionary. Have you created overridden `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods for the `IgaAdKey` class?

Comment: Thanks, but this printed wrong entries in wrong date, here is my full code: http://pastebin.com/ygKVKBjv 
Need help please..

Comment: @AhmedSaleh: Printed entries in the wrong date? There's no date in the information you show, nor is there any mention of dates in your question. You need to better explain what you're trying to accomplish.